# How to create a message with delayed visibility in node js for Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure

I am following the [Azure docs here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/storage/queues/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-queues.md#user-content-how-to-insert-a-message-into-a-queue) and trying to insert a message to a queue in `node.js` but I'd like the message to have a delayed visibility like ~ 10 minutes. How can I do that?

Comment: Hi,any updates now?Does my answer helps you?

Comment: @JayGong I ended up using Azure service bus which seems to be more light weighted than azure-storage. And didn't get time to test this yet. I'll come back once I get some real test for this. Thanks for the answer though, and it seems to me a valid solution.

Comment: Sure,waiting for your reply...

Comment: Hi,have you got some real test for this? Any updates?

Answer (score 0):

Just set `visibilityTimeout` property when you insert message.

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var accountName = '***'
var accountKey = '***'

var queueSvc = azure.createQueueService(accountName, accountKey);    
queueSvc.createMessage('jay', "Hello Jay", {visibilityTimeout : 15} ,function(error, results, response){
  if(!error){
    // Message inserted
  }
});

console.log("insert successfully")
```

Note: `visibilityTimeout` is defined as seconds.

Hope it helps you.